# How to include single row multiple column subquery (PIPELINED function) results in the result set

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pipelined-function

I am using Oracle 11g.

So, lets say that I have a test data table like this one

```
with test_data as (
    select 1 as id, 'John' as name from dual 
        union all
    select 2 as id, 'Jack' as name from dual
        union all
    select 3 as id, 'Peter' as name from dual
)
```

Also I have a `piplined` function that returns **one row** per call, with **multiple columns** like the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_PACK AS
  TYPE result_record is RECORD(
   surname           varchar2(27),
   telephone          varchar2(50),
   place_of_birth     varchar2(50)
       );

  TYPE result_table IS TABLE OF result_record;
  function runPipe(id number) RETURN result_table PIPELINED;
END ERC_PACK;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACK AS
    function runPipe(id number) RETURN result_table PIPELINED IS
    rec           result_record:=null;
    begin
       if  (id=1) then
         select 'Smih','139289289','Paris' into rec from dual;
       end if;
       if  (id=2) then
         select 'Lock','1888888888','London' into rec from dual;
       end if;
       if  (id=3) then
         select 'May','99999999999','Berlin' into rec from dual;
       end if;
       pipe row (rec);
       return;
  end;
END ERC_PACK;
/
```

And of course the

```
select * from table(MY_PACK.runPipe(1))
```

returns

```
Smih    139289289   Paris
```

Now I would like a select statement that will return all the rows of the `test_data`  along with the corresponding values from pipeline function

e.g. something like

```
select test_data.*, (select * from table(MY_PACK.runPipe(id))) from test_data
```

which **of course doses not work** 
but the **expected results** would be something like:

```
1 John  Smih    139289289   Paris
2 Jack  Lock    1888888888  London
3 Peter May     99999999999 Berlin
```

So how to achieve the above expected result, given the `test_data` table and the `pipelined` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this select :

```
    with test_data as (
    select 1 as id, 'John' as name from dual 
        union all
    select 2 as id, 'Jack' as name from dual
        union all
    select 3 as id, 'Peter' as name from dual
)
select td.*, s.*
from test_data td
LEFT JOIN  table(MY_PACK.runPipe(td.id)) s ON 1 = 1;
```

Comment: This works well. But you can put inner join rather than left join.

Comment: This actually worked - even with  `from test_data td,  table(MY_PACK.runPipe(td.id)) s` (no need for left join)  ... too bad one cannot do the same with  `from test_data td,  (select * table(MY_PACK.runPipe(td.id))) s ` it would be really helpful in my real world problem - however that wasn't in my initial question - so I am accepting. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OUTER APPLY`:

```
select td.*, s.*
from test_data td
outer apply (select * from table(MY_PACK.runPipe(td.id))) s
```

Comment: Is this for 12c? Any other way for 11g?

Comment: @Plirkee Oracle 12c

Comment: Unfortunately I have 11g ... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Try the below with alias

```
with test_data as (
select 1 as id, 'John' as name from dual 
    union all
select 2 as id, 'Jack' as name from dual
    union all
select 3 as id, 'Peter' as name from dual
)
select * from table(MY_PACK.runPipe(test_data.id))) from test_data
```